# Am I using Git in Eclipse the right way?

Tags: eclipse, git, github

Using Eclipse Juno on Windows. After struggling with Git a little bit, this is what I've come up with:

Note - at this point I want to be able to push to GitHub.

1. Set up a project
2. Put it under version control
3. Create a remote which is my GitHub repository
4. Push to the remote

However, I want to make it such that whenever I commit in Eclipse, it updates my GitHub repository automatically. Currently it only updates my local folders. Am I making sense here? How should I do this?

Also, why is it bad practice to use Git in the workspace of Eclipse? My directory structure looks like this on my local computer:

- ...workspace/ProjectName
- ...workspace/ProjectName/.git
- ...workspace/ProjectName/bin
- ...workspace/ProjectName/src

Thanks!

PS If this sounds really noob, yeah, I'm pretty new at version control but I figured I got to start from somewhere. Looked at all the tutorials online too, and this is what I came up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Auto pushing changes to the remote.**

With the latest version of the eGit plugin for Eclipse, there's a checkbox that will push every commit to the configured remote.

People coming from CVS/SVN typically auto-push to the remote. However, in a distributed version control system like Git I would advise against it. Especially in larger teams you don't necessarily want to push each commit to the remote for everyone to see.

**Directory structure**

There's a [write-up](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Considerations_for_Git_Repositories_to_be_used_in_Eclipse) on why Eclipse advises against creating the Repository within the Eclipse workspace.